# Flags mentioned as helpful, but still my remaining flags are reduced

Tags: support, flagging

I have flaged **4** posts and my profile says that all the flags are helpful(i.e. **4** posts flaged, **4** helpful flags). But when I tried to flag one more post, I saw that I had only **8** flags remaining. Even though **all my flags were deemed as helpful**. I want to know why two of my flags were gone,even though they were helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get 10 flags a day when you start out. Once used up, you have to wait until the next day to flag more posts. This is done to prevent new users from flagging everything they see and abusing the system. For every 10 helpful flags you have, you get allotted one more opportunity to flag a post each day. So don't worry, you'll get another 12 or so tomorrow

Answer (score 7):

From the [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts),

> **How many flags do I have?**
>
> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).